# Can we control progressive rendering in the Viewer based on the distance to the camera?

Tags: rendering, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have to work with very large models and we're hoping to use the first person camera to walk through them, and eventually do this in VR. The progressive rendering does wonders for improving perceived responsiveness, but it can be disorienting to have so many items around you disappear as you move.

Is there any way to turn progressive rendering off but only for objects closest to the camera? Maybe a number of objects up to a maximum number, or objects within a radius from the camera. Everything further away can load in later and flicker during motion, but it would be nice to keep the nearby objects rendered, especially structural objects like stairs. I've often walked towards stairs just to have them disappear in front of me, forcing me to fly to a platform with E and Q instead of walking.

So far I've only found a way to toggle progressive rendering for the entire model on or off with `viewer.setProgressiveRendering(bool)` but I haven't found a way to customize the rendering behavior.

Comment: Checking with Engineering to find a viable approach will get back soon

Comment: Per our Engineering's recommendation can you try set rendering targets with `viewer.impl.setFPSTargets(1, 5, 15)` and see it that helps? If not can you send the offending model over if possible (via a sharing service e.g. weTransfer/Dropbox/GDrive) with a brief description on steps to reproduce the issue to forge.help@autodesk.com?

Comment: That seems to be exactly the setting I was looking for. With a bit of testing it seems like (1, 15, 20) does what we need for this model. If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as accepted. The model is a Navisworks model hosted in Docs that has about 620000 fragments. It's an active construction model and can't really be shared, but the steps to reproduce the issue are just to load any large model into the viewer and walk through it in first person with the default viewer settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our Engineering's recommendation can you try set rendering targets with

```
viewer.impl.setFPSTargets(1, 5, 15) //min, target, max
```

In fact we've been having similar reports from other developers requesting similar capability to fine tune rendering with large models so our Engineering is considering their options to extend on existing functions and even build them into extensions.